# load a part of the page without refreshing it

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I am pretty new to web design. I just finished my first static website. 
What i dont like about it is that the page often reload (each time you change section)

My question is "how to make this kind of nav : http://www.doblin.com/work/#innovation-strategy"

As you see the page doesnt reload when you click on "Set Innovation Strategy / Design, Build + Launch Innovations / Become Better Innovators"

How it s done ?

Is it possible on a static website (html/css/jquery) without sql or so (it may require ajax or ...) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at the code, this page uses some jQuery functions to do this work, check it out:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){

    var hash = location.hash;

    // if a hash has been set
    if(hash !== '') {

        showContent(hash, origSections);

    } else {

        // pass in "empty" hash
        showContent('', origSections);

    }


    return false;

});

// call hashchange on initial page load
$(window).hashchange();


// ----------- SHOW CONTENT  ----------- //
function showContent(active, all) {

    if (jQuery.support.opacity) {
        opacity = true;
    } else {
        opacity = false;
    }
```

This can also be done using CSS3 transitions and animations. Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FknGD) based on [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/30/page-transitions-with-css3/) Codrops tutorial. I particularly think this is a better approach

But if you want to get dynamic data from somewhere, i advise you to use Ajax(There are some cool jQuery stuff to handle this)

Answer (score 0):

Take a (hard) look at JQuery or Dojo, any of them will be your friend.

Your example uses JQuery.

It can be done on one static page without worries.

Here you have some demos: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

You can also study jquery on http://w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery on your static website. You can go through below link
[Jquery](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/31/50-jquery-function-demos-for-aspiring-web-developers/)

But if you wish to save data and retrieve from server then you need to use Ajax to avoid refreshing page.There are many tutorials available on how to use Ajax